# Use varchar date field for date range function in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a varchar date field of the following format -

```
ACCOUNTING_DATE
---------------
2014/01/07
```

Now, I want to use a date range function using the below -

```
select * 
from table
where (ACCOUNTING_DATE >= convert(varchar(10),'01/01/2014',101)
and ACCOUNTING_DATE <= convert(varchar(10),'12/31/2014',101))
```

which is not returning me the correct results. Can you please help with a better way to achieve the same? Thanks.

Comment: Can you change the field to  `date`? That would be best

Comment: Think a moment what you have here, on both sides there is comparison of strings. It has nothing to do with date except column name `ACCOUNTING_DATE`

Comment: @juergend - The field has to remain a varchar. I cannot change the datatype of the columns in the raw tables.

Comment: The "best" way to achieve results is to stop using varchar columns to hold dates. I don't know why this is so popular but it is is nothing but painful. I don't understand why you are using convert on a string literal with a format. Those converts are totally pointless.

Comment: @Kritner actually cast/convert from a datetime to a date is one of the few times that a function in the where clause is SARGable. The engine is able to perform that conversion and not force an index scan.

Comment: @SeanLange oh thanks, glad I didn't post it in my answer then :)

Comment: @SeanLange er wait... but in OPs instance it would be varchar to a date - that wouldn't meet the condition you stated would it?

Comment: Nope. For this case it would have to convert a string to a date which is definitely not sargable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert to `date` to do a date compare, otherwise you're doing a `string` compare.

```
select * 
from table
where convert(date, ACCOUNTING_DATE) between '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31'
```

In addition, if you're storing dates, you should use `date` columns, not `varchar` - as you run into issues such as yours.

Comment: Add also about SET DATEFORMAT so he won't be surprised when he get CONVERSION ERROR out of range.

Comment: I agree but would suggest using the ANSI format for string dates to avoid issues with dateformat. '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31'.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the accounting date to a date before comparing:

```
where cast(Accounting_Date as date) between '1-1-14' and '12-31-14'
```

If you really just want to check whether it is during 2014, you can also take that portion of the string separately:

```
where left(accounting_date, 4) = 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

You currently have a couple of conditions of the form `[varchar] < [date]`. The database will convert the date to a varchar (the fact that's it a call to `convert` on a string literal is inconsequential) and compare them lexicographically.

The "right" solution would probably be to change the column type to a real `date` column. If this is not possible, you could explicitly convert both sides of the comparison to `date`s:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   mytable
WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), accounting_date, 101) >= 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'01/01/2014',101) AND
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), accounting_date, 101) <=   
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'12/31/2014',101))
```